# TypeLoad Exception on Mysql .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, dll, mono

I am currently on .NET 3.5 UnityEngine, Mono and was trying to add Mysql support for my project.

I literally tried a lot of versions from the downloads (v2) as references and placed the dlls in the right places but I get a typeload exception.

Platform assembly: f:\adt\RustLegacyServer\rust_server_Data\Managed\MySql.Data.dll (this message is harmless)
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MySQLConnector' from assembly 'Test, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

It doesn't want to load my class from my dll, because that's where It loads the Mysql dll, or uses It.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer thanks to a Contributor

Copy the "System.Data.dll" from "Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity" to the DLL's folder you use in your project tree

It may be necessary to do this with the "I18N.dll", "I18N.West.dll" files.
I was using the MC System.Data for the JSON API, was working fine, but apparently Mysql didn't like that on the Unity platform for some reason. Json seems to be working with that dll too.

System.Transactions.dll might be also required. If all of these are there, Unity won't have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can't find it. Is f a virtual drive or a real one? 
You can get a lot of problems, if you load your references from a virtual drive, use a UNC path or a real drive for this.

Better way is to use nuget. It stores all packages in the same folder where your project be and you can select every time the newst version or the version you need.

Or maybe it is the wrong version of your DLL. You need another one.

Comment: This is actually a game that I modify using CIL. All the reference dlls should go to managed folder, It never had problems finding It. The log even says "Platform assembly",  so It's kinda weird. The disc is not virtual. Cannot use nuget, and It's not necessary in this situation. There is a possibility that It somehow doesn't detect It. Let me try some stuff.

Comment: Do I need any extra reference for the mysql dlls?

Comment: Did you download a mySQL Connector (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) or did you take the DLLs simply from the folder, where the MySQL Application ist installed? Because, I downloaded and installed every time the MySQL Connector. If you go to your solution and choose "Add Reference", you will see all MySQL Libs in a window.